# assigning an HTML value to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Javascript function that allows me to add a new row to my table:

```
$(function() {

var $table = $('table.pv-data'),
    counter = 1;

$('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;            
var newRow = 
        '<tr>' + 
            '<td><input type="text" name="id' + counter + '"/></td>' +
            '<td><select name="state' + counter + '"/><OPTION value= "persil">Persil</OPTION><OPTION value= "other">Other</OPTION></select></td> ' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="longitude' + counter + '"/></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="latitude' + counter + '"/></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="altitude' + counter + '"/></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="module_tilt' + counter + '"/></td>' +
            '<td><a href="#" class="remove">remove</a></td>'
        '</tr>';
    $table.append(newRow);
    });
});
```

Everything is working fine, just the part where I have to select between the options:"Persil" or "Other" is not working. it's not showing the different options.

Comment: Of course won't work. You are closing the select tag too early.
`<select name="state'+counter'">` should be correct

Comment: @KiaMorot Oh ok, didn't pay attention to that

Comment: As a side note, if you do a lot of this, you may want to consider using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#readme)

Comment: FYI, you're missing a `+` after the second to last line of HTML. It's actually harmless here, but it excludes the closing `</tr>`.

Comment: @KiaMorot Write this as an answer and I'll +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines need to be replaced

1. `'<td><select name="state' + counter + '"/>...'`.
   Is not correct as you are closing the select tag too early.
2. `'<td><a href="#" class="remove">remove</a></td>'`. You are missing `+` at the end.

by these replacements:

1. `'<td><select name="state' + counter + '">...'`.
2. `'<td><a href="#" class="remove">remove</a></td>' +`

Note: Replacement#2 is pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Take away the self-closing tag from the end of the opening `select` tag and remove the space between the `value= "persil"` in both of the `option` elements.  Also add a + to concatenate the final `</tr>`.

```
var newRow = 
    '<tr>' + 
        '<td><input type="text" name="id' + counter + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><select name="state' + counter + '"><OPTION value="persil">Persil</OPTION><OPTION value="other">Other</OPTION></select></td> ' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="longitude' + counter + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="latitude' + counter + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="altitude' + counter + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="module_tilt' + counter + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><a href="#" class="remove">remove</a></td>' +
    '</tr>';
```

Having the self closing tag at the end of an element (the slash at the end, as in `<img src="..." />`) is only for elements without an independent closing tag, so for something like `<select>` you do not need it as this function is fulfilled by the `</select>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in this line:

```
'<td><select name="state' + counter + '"/><OPTION value= "persil">P
```

The select have it own closing tag it must be like this

```
'<td><select name="state' + counter + '"><OPTION value= "persil">P
```